# Not able to take multiple window titles to arraylist

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was working on handling multiple windows. I want to take the titles of each window into an array and print it..But while using the below code, the array prints only the parent window titlename:

how to resolve this issue?

```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   driver.get("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.com/");

   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Multiple window examples")).click();
   String parentWindw = driver.getWindowHandle();

   ArrayList Titles = new ArrayList();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-body- 
   6170641642826198246\"]/a[1]")).click(); 
   Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

   driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-body- 
   6170641642826198246\"]/a[2]")).click();
   Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

   driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-body- 
   6170641642826198246\"]/a[3]")).click();
   //System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
   Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

   driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

   Set allWindwHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
   int winCount = allWindwHandles.size();
   System.out.println(winCount);

   ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(allWindwHandles);


   for (int j = 1;j<winCount;j++){
   driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(j));
   System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
   System.out.println(Titles.get(j-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding browser-title to "Titles" ArrayList you have to switch to newly opened window and then perform getTitle

**Please refer  Modified Code :**

```
package practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class WindowSwitchProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\win\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Multiple window examples")).click();
        String parentWindw = driver.getWindowHandle();

        ArrayList Titles = new ArrayList();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-body-6170641642826198246']/a[1]")).click();

        Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-body-6170641642826198246\"]/a[2]")).click();
        driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());
        Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-body-6170641642826198246\"]/a[3]")).click();
        //System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[2].toString());
        Titles.add(driver.getTitle());

        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindw);

        Set allWindwHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        int winCount = allWindwHandles.size();
        System.out.println(winCount);

        ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(allWindwHandles);


        for (int j = 1; j < winCount; j++) {
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(j).toString());
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            System.out.println(Titles.get(j - 1));
        }
    }
}
```